# Empty File constructor is neither file nor directory

Tags: java, file, file-io

What is the difference between the following two methods for creating a file?

```
new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
new File("");
```

Java identifies the first one as a directory, and the second one's **neither a file nor a directory**! Why is that the case?

---

Code:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
        System.out.println("File Created with CurrentDir taken From System Props");
        File f1 = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        System.out.println("Absolute Path: " + f1.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("isDirectory: " + f1.isDirectory());
        System.out.println("isFile: " + f1.isFile());

        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("File Created with Empty String Path");
        File f2 = new File("");
        System.out.println("Absolute Path: " + f2.getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("isdirectory: " + f2.isDirectory());
        System.out.println("isFile: " + f2.isFile());       
    }
}
```

Output:

```
File Created with CurrentDir taken From System Props
Absolute Path: D:\Java Workspace\my_Workspace\JavaTest
isDirectory: true
isFile: false

File Created with Empty String Path
Absolute Path: D:\Java Workspace\my_Workspace\JavaTest
isdirectory: false
isFile: false
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the old File API instead of the modern NIO? The `File` class is outdated. Consider using `Files´, `Paths` and `Path` instead.

Comment: Besides _file_ and _directory_ there is more, and `list` might return null. There can be several _file systems_ (best covered by `Path` as mentioned). The empty string cannot say anything, Linux "/", UNC "//MyComputer/", Windows "D:/" already give an entry point.

Comment: That question is a good find. And, if you ask me, one of the many reasons why one should rather use NIO instead. You wouldn't have that problem with NIO. `Files.isDirectory(Paths.get(""));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation

It may seem a little **non-intuitive** but actually that's just how the class is **supposed to work** according to its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html). It's called *empty abstract pathname* in the documentation:

> The empty abstract pathname has no prefix and an *empty name sequence*.

And from your constructor `File#File(String)`:

> Creates a new File instance by converting the given pathname string into an abstract pathname. If the given string is the empty string, then the result is the **empty abstract pathname**.

So the `File` class actually interprets the *empty name* as actual name. When you test `File#isDirectory()` or `File#isFile()` it thus checks if there exists a file or directory like

```
D:\Java Workspace\iTAW_Workspace\JavaTest\<empty>
```

Note the `<empty>` which I wrote to indicate that it actually searches for a file here with the *empty name*. Obviously such a file can not exist, thus the result will always be `false`. So again, it does not check

```
D:\Java Workspace\iTAW_Workspace\JavaTest\
```

but rather the *empty file* in this directory, which does not exist.

Unfortunately you don't see this when using the `File#toAbsolutePath()` method as there is no representation for an *empty name*.

---

### NIO

Note that the class `File` and everything related to it is **outdated**. Nowadays file IO is done using NIO revolving around `Files`, `Paths` and `Path`. This API is much more cleaner and more intuitive. It will also work as intended on your current example:

```
Files.isDirectory(Paths.get("")); // true
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a file with empty string results to creating a File instance which **actually does not exist** and its absolute pathname is "empty abstract pathname".

-> **That's why the second one's neither a file nor a directory for you**.

The reason behind that, a maybe little bit confusing output for you, is definition located in javadocs:

> If this abstract pathname is the empty abstract pathname then the
>   pathname string of the current user directory, which is named by the
>   system property user.dir, is returned.

You can find more about this topic here
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Currently this only hints into the right direction. Instead, try to give a full answer explaining every detail (see [answer]).

Comment: @Zabuza: `getAbsolutePath` is explicitly documented to return the current working directory when called on the empty abstract pathname.

Comment: @Zabuza from java doc "if this abstract pathname is the empty abstract pathname then the pathname string of the current user directory, which is named by the  system property 'user.dir' is returned"

Comment: You don't need to explain that to me. Instead, **edit** the answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

new File("") creates new file with relative (empty) path. As this file doesn't exist both isDirectory() and isFile() return false (corresponds to javadoc).

From javadoc

> boolean java.io.File.isDirectory()
>
> ...
>
> Returns: true if and only if
>   the file denoted by this abstract pathname exists and is a directory;
>   false otherwise

The same is true for isFile(). and as long as your file doesn't exist both methods return false.

Comment: And why is that not the case? `getAbsolutePath()` clearly shows that the file *points* to an existing directory. Please explain the details.

Comment: It shows the same but it is different. In first case the path is `user.dir path` when in the second case the path is `user.dir path + empty string`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the difference between the Java object File and a file actually present on your computer.

In the first case : `new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"))`. You create a Java object File and give him a path : `System.getProperty("user.dir")`. Later when you call the function `.getAbsolutePath()` it returns you the path you gave. Then when you call `.isDirectory()` it tells you true because there is a directory corresponding to this Java object File.

---

In the second case, `new File("")` it creates a Java object File and you give it a path : `""`. Since the path given is not absolute, the system will resolve it as a relative from the user.dir path.

*from [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)*

> A pathname, whether abstract or in string form, may be either absolute or relative. An absolute pathname is complete in that no other information is required in order to locate the file that it denotes. A relative pathname, in contrast, must be interpreted in terms of information taken from some other pathname. By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked.

Later when you call the function `.getAbsolutePath()` it returns you the path you gave, so the path to user dir + empty string : `D:\Java Workspace\iTAW_Workspace\JavaTest\<empty>`. Then when you call `.isDirectory()` it tells you false because there is no directory corresponding to this path. (same reason for `isFile()`)

Comment: Maybe you can be more precise on the last part, why `isDirectory()` returns `false`. The reason is because the method tries to check the *file* with *empty name*. So like `D:\Java Workspace\iTAW_Workspace\JavaTest\<empty>` but there exists nothing like `<empty>`, thus the `false`. Obviously this can never be the case, thus its always `false`. Nonetheless, good and clear answer :)